# Cómo referenciar a controladores en diferentes archivos dentro de la configuración de las rutas en ngRoute

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

En AngularJS defino la configuracion de ruta para la aplicacion, como se muestra:

```js
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider
 .when('/', {
  templateUrl: 'partes/home/home.html',
  controller: 'homeCtrl'
 })
 .otherwhise({
   template: '404'
 });
}]);

app.controller('homeCtrl', homeCtrl);
homeCtrl.$injection = ['$scope', '$location'];
function homeCtrl($scope, $location) {
 $scope.ingresar = function() {
  $location.path('/ingresar');
 };
 $scope.registrar = function() {
  $location.path('/registrar');
 };
}
```

En este ejemplo el controlador esta dentro del mismo archivo js/app.js, lo que quiero es poder crear un  archivo de controlador distinto, ejemplo: js/controlador/homeCtrl.js que contenga el controlador y que al cargar la plantilla se cargue o ejecute el controlador que esta en otra ruta.

Answer (score 0):

La idea es que construyas tu aplicacion de forma modularizada y de la misma forma separes controllers, services, directives, factories, etc.

Por tanto los elementos deben crearse con forma [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

```
(function (){

  function controller(inject1, inject2, inject3){
    vm = this;

    function someFunction(){
      // public method
    }

    function somePrivateMethod(){
      //private method
    }

    vm.someFunction = someFunction;
    return vm;
  }

  angular.module('app')
         .controller('myController', controller);
  //Se incluyen dependencias
  controller.$inject = ['inject1', 'inject2', 'inject3']
})();
```

de la misma forma se declara el resto de los archivos que compongan la aplicación. Puedes tomar como referencia esta guía de estilo para que puedas estructurar tu aplicacion:

[toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide](https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide/tree/angular-old-es5)